# Почему не загружается страница корзины woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: не загружается страница корзины woocommerce. Вчера утром все прекрасно работало, сделал правки, убедился, что все в порядке. С обеда и по нынешнюю минуту не загружается и все (в браузере Chrome). В браузере Firefox выдает ошибку 502 bad gateway.

На странице корзины два шорткода:

[woocommerce_cart]
[woocommerce_checkout]

Если я убираю шорткод первый(шорткод корзины), все прекрасно загружается.

Та же проблема с карточками товаров. Все прекрасно работало\загружалось, сейчас нет. Что могло произойти ? (с проектом работаю я один, вариант, что кто-то мог как-то сломать код быть не может)

Кеш, куки чистил, плагин woocommerce выключал и включал.

Не понимаю что не так.

Comment: если включаю тему storefront все замечательно работате

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте включить debug в файле `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );     // включение дебаг режима
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); // true - логирование ошибок в файл /wp-content/debug.log
```

И выложите что появилось в файле `debug.log`.

Comment: стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос